# Downloading A File From Online Without Changing File Name

Tags: vba, download

I want to download a file but the code snippet I have requires you to enter a file name. I want to keep the name of the file it downloads for simplicity sake.

The code I'm using is:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
"linkToDownloadFrom",
"nameOfDownloadedFile")
```

Comment: The reason for the name of the download file is for you to provide a location for the file to be saved. Try to pass a folder name or blank string to keep the same name. If that doesn't work then you can parse the URL to get the file name and use that.

Comment: An empty string returns:
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Argument cannot be Nothing.
Parameter name: destinationFileName'

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127875(v=vs.110).aspx Based on the documentation, you will need to pass a file name. If you do not know the file name, you can use the URI and split it using `/` and get the last item from the result.